# CSS transition underline reveal

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a CSS transition in which the underline appears from bottom to top when you hover over an href element.

I found this example, which creates an underline appearing from left to right on hover.

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;    
    margin-right: 39px; 
    width: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
            transition: 0.3s ease;
}

a:hover {
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
            transition: 0.3s ease;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    width: 30px;
    margin-right: 9px;
}
```

How does this have to be modified to create an underline appearing from bottom to top on hover?

I appreciate your help,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this animation sweets your needs using css keyframes :

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59mh93p1/)**

**CSS**

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;     
    margin-right: 39px; 
    width: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.9s ease;
            transition: 0.9s ease;
}



a:hover span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
    width: 120px;
    margin-right: 9px;
    -webkit-animation: mymove infinite 1s alternate;
    -o-animation: mymove infinite 1s alternate;
    animation: mymove infinite 1s alternate;
    -webkit-transition: 0.9s ease;
            transition: 0.9s ease;

}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 24px;}
    to {top: 9px;}
} 

/* Standard syntax */ 
@keyframes mymove {
    from {top: 24px;}
    to {top: 9px;}
}
```

an other version **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59mh93p1/1/)**

Comment: Almost :)
I am sorry if I havent described it correctly.
The underline should grow (get thicker) on hover from the bottom up to where the text start.
So it grows from bottom to the bottom of the letter.
Does that make sense?

Comment: I found a solution.
I will check your answer as correct since it basically did what I asked for.
Thanks